# Reducing and sum on a Set of multiple objects and multiple criteria

Tags: java, java-stream

Following exercise gives me a headache.

I would like to merge a set or list of objects according to several criteria and sum up some attributes, but keep the remaining attributes, which are always the same.

Let's assume following class (for illustrative purposes):

```java
public class Payment {
  BigDecimal amount;  // --> aggregate 1 with sum
  Long quantity; // aggregate 2 with sum
  LocalDate date;   // criteria 1
  String paymentGroup;  // criteria 2
  String currency;  // --> keep as is (or FindFirst)
  String type// --> keep as is (or findFirst
}
```

and following input data:

```java
new Payment(new BigDecimal(100), 15L, "2023-07-20", "G1", "EUR", "Lorem ipsum");  // -> Reduce to #1
new Payment(new BigDecimal(200), 10L, "2023-07-20", "G1", "EUR", "Lorem ipsum");  // -> Reduce to #1
new Payment(new BigDecimal(300), 10L, "2023-07-20", "G2", "EUR", "Lorem dipsum"); // -> Reduce to #2
new Payment(new BigDecimal(400), 20L, "2023-07-20", "G2", "EUR", "Lorem dipsum"); // -> Reduce to #2
new Payment(new BigDecimal(500), 25L, "2023-07-21", "G2", "EUR", "Ipsum dolor");  // -> Reduce to #3
```

Should result in a Set or List of (preserve Dimensions and Attributes):

```
Payment[300, 25, "2023-07-20", "G1", "EUR", "Lorem ipsum"],
Payment[700, 30, "2023-07-20", "G2", "EUR", "Lorem dipsum"],
Payment[500, 25, "2023-07-21", "G2", "EUR", "Lorem dipsum"]
```

The guarantee of an initial sorted list is not given.

Any clean idea with reduce(), groupingBy() with java11 or greater, maybe with a custom comparator/hashCode etc. (or using a library for that) would be great.
Extensible criteria columns for reduction without extensive nesting would be supreme.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some kind of hashing. You will need to override the methods Java uses to compare keys for equality so that keys are equal if everything except their amount matches. Using `Set<Payment>` to build this feels pretty bad since

1. `Payment`s will inevitably be considered equal despite having different amounts
2. It requires mutating `Set` keys that are considered equal even though they are in fact not

Avoiding mutating the keys makes this is a much better case for `HashMap`. I would probably also add a utility class to hold the overridden equality methods.

```java
class PaymentDetails extends Payment {

    public PaymentDetails(Payment payment) {
        super(payment);
    }

    // override your methods (`hashCode` and `equals`) using the superclass properties
}

class Payment {

    private PaymentDetails details;

    public PaymentDetails getDetails() {
        if (details == null) details = new PaymentDetails(this);
        return details;
    }
}

Map<PaymentDetails, BigDecimal> dailyNetTransactions = new HashMap<>();

PaymentDetails details;
payments.forEach(payment -> {
    details = payment.getDetails();
    if (!dailyNetTransactions.containsKey(details)) {
        dailyNetTransactions.put(details, payment.amount);
    } else {
        dailyNetTransactions.get(details) += payment.amount;
    }
});
```

I don't write Java and the circular-ish class setup feels a bit off but hopefully I captured the general idea.